# image wont fill the buttons size it will just have weird side margins no matter the image size

Tags: html, css

```
<button id="popout-button" onclick="popout"><img id="popoutMenuImg" src="Images/menuicon.png" alt="menu"></img></button>
```

this is the button and image

```
#popout-button { width: 4%; padding: 10px; background: none; background-size: 100%;}
```

button style

```
#popout #popoutMenuImg {padding: 0px; height: auto; width: 40px;}
```

img style
im new o webdev i know its messy

Comment: change `padding: 10px` to `padding: 0` in `#popout-button`

Comment: Do  you want the button to be a fixed shape - e.g. a square?